# Are you a college student studying music or a music teacher, and like free food?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

If so, I would love to get in touch with you. I'm looking for high school or college students or teachers (or anyone who has connections to a music learning community) who might be interested in helping me kick off/formalize a pizza ambassador-type program. Basically, you would help promote the music.SE community *in the real world* - what a crazy idea!

The goal is to establish a program that can be replicated by any Stack Exchange ambassador in any location. Since Stack Exchange HQ is in New York City, I would love to get in touch with college students or music teachers from NYC metro area, but we would love to involve anyone who wants to help promote the site.

Additionally, let me know if you have any questions, concerns, or suggestions for how to make a great ambassador program.

**Edit:** This is inspired by the [Google pizza ambassador](http://www.knowledgesutra.com/forums/topic/27156-google-pizza-program-for-students-only/) program, but we will be customizing our own program to fit SE's style and needs.

**Edit 2:** This program is open to any music student or teacher, in any location; if you'd like to get involved and help grow this community, please reply here or email laura@stackexchange.com.

**UPDATE** I've started putting up flyers on some local New York City Campuses to see if there are any students not currently using the site who might like to get involved. **However, if any current user, located anywhere, would like to be an ambassador, or volunteer to put up flyers on *your* local campus, please let me know here or email me** (laura@stackexchange.com).

Comment: Feel free to send me an email with details, I have some ties to my local uni and i'm involved in the music scene here.

Comment: @DRL I emailed you at the beginning of the week. If you didn't get my email, let me know, and I'll resend. I look forward to talking to you more about this!

Comment: What about putting in the title that this only concerns New Yorkers?

Comment: It's not limited to New Yorkers; the edit on September 23 says that. I'll bold the relevant part to make it more obvious, though.

Comment: Send me the details as well please. Sounds like alot of fun.