# Should we encourage homework questions? If so, how?

Tags: discussion, topics

I could see Music.SE potentially being a home for "homework" questions much like StackOverflow.  Undergraduates in music theory courses in particular might find this site a good place to ask such questions.

Should we encourage these questions?  If so, how?

I believe we should encourage these questions if they do not start to dominate the site, but I would not know how to encourage any specific types of questions.  That said, though, I'd really like more questions in areas I can answer...

Answer (score 1):

I've thought of this as well, in particular targeting undergrads as you mention.  Their questions shouldn't be *too* basic and thus hopefully useful to have on the site.  Our CHAOS promotion person, Laura, [has also thought of this](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274/are-you-a-college-student-studying-music-or-a-music-teacher-and-like-free-food).  If you care to get involved in outreach, I suggest contacting her.  I think that's the best way to encourage these questions -- they're certainly on-topic and we have happily accepted theory questions before, so I think we need to focus externally more than internally.